# Get column names to show and store in another table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

In laravel 5.1 it is giving en error UNDEFINED INDEX::cost_group

I want to show courses table's column name by drop down in another payments view page and store it into another table(payments) when one of them is selected

My `PaymentsController.php`:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
        $filter = $request->input();
        $sort = $request->query();
        $payments = Payment::filter($filter)->sort($sort)->paginate(10);

        foreach(Course::all() as $course) {
            $data['courses'][$course->id] = $course->name;
            $data['courses'][$course->cost_group]=$course->course_cost;
            $data['courses'][$course->cost_minigroup]=$course->course_name;
            $data['courses'][$course->cost_individual]=$course->course_name;

        }

        return view('payments.index', compact('payments', 'data'));
    }
```

My form.blade.php (of payments)

```
<div class="ui form">
             <div class="field">
                 <div class="ui selection dropdown">
                     <input type="hidden" name="amount" id="course_val" />
                     <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                     <div class="default text">Course type</div>
                     <div class="menu">
                         <div class="item course_val" data-value="{{$data['cost_group']}}">Group</div>
                         <div class="item course_val" data-value="{{$data['cost_minigroup']}}">Minigroup</div>
                         <div class="item course_val" data-value="{{$data['cost_individual']}}">Individual</div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: `var_dump($data)` I bet it's not holding what you think it's holding.

Comment: @aynber what you mean??

Comment: Meaning that your indexes are not named 'cost_group', 'cost_minigroup', and 'cost_individual'. The indexes are whatever the value of `$course->cost_group`, `$course->cost_minigroup`, and `$course->cost_individual`. When you var_dump your variable, you can see the indexes and values.

Comment: @aynber yeah. But how you get the table columns  in drop down and store in another table if your table like this
courses{ id, name, cost_group, cost_minigroup, cost_individual}' these are all columns.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but if you want to use static index names, then specify them yourself instead of using the database values as indexes.

Comment: @aynber it is not duplicate of any other question.Cause I looked through the question  did not find any answer. You guys marked it as duplicate for your reputation.

Comment: @RiggsFolly it is not duplicate of any other question.Cause I looked through the question  did not find any answer. You guys marked it as duplicate for your reputation.

Comment: So please unmark it if possible so other experts could see it and help?!

Comment: Voting to close does not affect our reputation, and it is just like every other undefined index question out there. The data variable does not contain the indexes you think it does. Dump the variable, *look* at the structure, then decide if you need to access the data another way, or build up the data another way.

Comment: Ok i will try thank you.